# Finding Volume of a Torus (Spherical Coordinates)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

**Question:** Find volume of region bounded by torus where equation of torus in spherical coordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$ is $r=2 \sin \phi$ for $\phi \in [0, \pi]$ and $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$.

**Attempt:** Graphing $r=2 \sin \phi$ for $\phi \in [0, \pi]$ shows that $r \in [0, 2]$. Using this as my bounds for integration:

Volume = $\iiint_V 1 dV = \int^\pi_0 \int^{2\pi}_0 \int^2_0 r^2 \sin (\phi) dr d\theta d\phi$ where $r^2 \sin (\phi)$ is the Jacobian for spherical coordinates.

I then evaluated the integral to get an answer for the volume as $\frac{32\pi}{3}$ cubic units, however am unsure of my working to determine the bounds of $r$.

Is this correct?

Comment: No, the upper bound on $r$ has to be $2 \sin \phi$

Comment: @peek-a-boo Since $r$ is a radius would you still then say the lower bound is 0?

Comment: yes that's right. Because if we let $\xi(r,\phi, \theta) = (r \sin\phi\cos\theta, r\sin\phi\sin\theta, r\cos\phi)$ be the polar coordinate map, and we let $U = \{(r, \phi, \theta)| \, \, r \in [0,2 \sin \phi]\, \phi \in [0,\pi], \, \theta \in [0,2\pi]\}$, then what the question says is that the image set $\xi[U] = V$ is exactly the torus. Hence, $\int_V 1 \, dV = \int_{\xi[U]} 1 \, dV = \int_U |\det \xi'(r, \phi,\theta)|\, dr \, d \phi\, d \theta$, which if you simplify is almost the expresion you get, except for changing the upper limit to $2 \sin \phi$.